# Docker image specific argument in ECS task definition

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, selenoid

I have the below docker run command to launch a container:

```js
docker run -d --name selenoid-ui  \
    --link selenoid                 \
    -p 8080:8080                    \
    aerokube/selenoid-ui --selenoid-uri=http://selenoid:4444
```

- Manage to run the command except the --selenoid-uri=http://selenoid:4444 part.
- Tried to put the same in docker command, entry point and key value pairs but doesnt seem to work.

Any idea where shall I use this docker image specific argument in task definition?

Comment: How did you manage to add --name, --link, -p in ECS run_task python ? If you share the details, it would be really great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this: Advanced container configuration > Environment > Command

--selenoid-uri=http://selenoid:4444

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Command` property in your ContainerDefinition. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions.html#cfn-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinition-command